# pass tabular argument from \newcommand

Tags: tables, arguments, csvsimple

I want to pass the tabular argument|p{5cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{8cm}| from the newcommand \csvautotabularcenter{2.csv} since it will change as the number of columns change based on the input file . I know you can add a third argument but for some reason it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{2.csv}
    name,type,random
    sample 1,type 1,"some really long text"
    sample 2,type 2,"another long text"
    sample 3,type 3,"unbelivelably long text"
    sample 4,type 4,"just random text"
    sample 5,type 5,"the end"
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\csvset{
autotabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{8cm}|}\csv@tablehead, %want to input |p{5cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{8cm}| from  \csvautotabularcenter{2.csv}
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautotabularcenter}[2][respect underscore=true]{\csvloop{autotabularcenter={#2},#1}}

\csvautotabularcenter{2.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable tex code and some data we can play with? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: unfortunately I cant provide the exact data but its mostly long texts instead of numbers. As for the compliable code its exactly as above just with begin/end document and userpackage csvsimple

Comment: make your code compilable. You can provide some sample data with the filecontents environment.

Comment: it really helps if you don't make us guess how to complete the example, please edit the question to make the example a complete document and a second code block with some sample data